# update django models column based on other column

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have a model like

```
class tbl_payment(models.Model):
    document_id                     = models.ForeignKey(tbl_invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client_id                       = models.ForeignKey(tbl_customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_amount                    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    paid_amount                     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    balance                         = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    date                            = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    status                          = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Now what I want to do is whenever a new record is added, or an existing record changes, `balance` should be updated as the difference between `total_amount` and `paid_amount` (simple maths), and based on my `balance` column, I want to save `status` as **Paid**, **Partial** or **Unpaid**.

I want to refrain from calculating the `balance` in my views and then saving in the database, instead, I want to handover this part to my models so that my models take care of the `balance` and I may avoid errors which I am subconsciously afraid of.

I came to know that this is done something like this

```
class tbl_payment(models.Model):
    document_id                     = models.ForeignKey(tbl_invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client_id                       = models.ForeignKey(tbl_customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_amount                    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    paid_amount                     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    balance                         = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    date                            = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    status                          = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    @property
    def balance(self, value):
        return self.total_amount - paid_amount
```

but what should I pass in place of `value`??
also when I try to get `due_amount` value like this

```
tbl_bulk_payment.objects.get(pk=1).due_amount
```

it gives `due_amount() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'`

what is the correct way of doing this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to override `clean()` function.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

> `Model.clean()` ... to modify attributes on your model ...

```py
    class tbl_payment(models.Model):
        class Status(models.TextChoices):
            paid = 'Paid', 'Paid'
            partial = 'Partial', 'Partial'
            unpaid = 'Unpaid', 'Unpaid'
            
        document_id                     = models.ForeignKey(tbl_invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        client_id                       = models.ForeignKey(tbl_customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        total_amount                    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
        paid_amount                     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
        balance                         = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
        date                            = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
        status                          = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Status.choices)
    
        def clean(self):
            self.balance = self.total_amount - self.paid_amount
            
            if self.balance >= 0:
                self.status = Status.paid
            elif self.paid_amount == 0:
                self.status = Status.unpaid
            else:
                self.status = Status.partial
```

P.S. your Model class name is not following the python or Django naming rule.
`class Payment(models.Model)` would be better.

and `document_id` => `document`. because

```py
payment = Payment.objects.get(pk=1)
payment.document_id
```

in this case `payment.document_id` would return `document` instance. (not document instance's id). so `document` is more Django like style than `document_id`

Comment: yeah, it helps!!! thanks!!  but is there any other way of doing it without having to override the save() method?? just curious to know

Comment: It can be done through web page to database workflow (HTML => View => Form => Model). If you uses `forms.py`, it can be done at some form classes like `SomeModelForm`. and it can be done at `views.py` (not recommended). but in this case models.py is appropriate place to be.

Comment: I guess I will be sticking to the above answer now, it solves the problem and is much convenient... :D

Comment: there are several ways to place business logic :) readmore => https://sunscrapers.com/blog/where-to-put-business-logic-django/

Comment: The save() method is not a good place to modify values. I edited the original answer.